# iPhone - MapKit : How may I customize the color and alpha of an overlay on the fly?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, overlay, customization

I have a MapView onto which I put some overlays (MKPolygon).
I have to maintain groups of MKPolygon.

For this, I have a PolyGonGroupClass that keeps each poly and the color and alpha that should be used to display all these polygons.

So, each time I find a poly, I add it as a map overlay and memorize in into the correct group of polys.
All my groups of poly are kepts into an instance var.

```
[self.mapView addOverlay:poly];
[thecorrectpolygroup addObject:poly];
...
[self.mypolygroups addObject:thecorrectpolygroup];


@interface PolyGonGroupClass : NSObject {
    UIColor* __color;
    float __alpha;
    NSMutableArray* __polygons;
}
```

Well...

At this point, how may I tell to the MapView the color and alpha of each poly and update them on the fly when one of these color change ?

I found a `- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay` method, but I don't see how I may use it to retrieve the values I put into the memorised values.

I guess I should use the overlay parameter, but how may I retrieve the correct group of poly that correspond to that overlay ?

Comment: You could call [mapView setNeedsDisplay]; which I am pretty sure forces the layers to redraw also.

Comment: @Lee Armstrong : the question is not how to force the redraw (your tip is correct), but how may I personnalise each overlay.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You need to use the polygons in the viewForOverlay and mapkit will o the drawing for you. What code have you got in viewForOverlay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewForOverlay`, you can loop through your `mypolygroups` array and check if the overlay is in that group's `polygons` array:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView *pv = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay] autorelease];

        for (PolyGonGroupClass *pgc in mypolygroups) 
        {
            if ([pgc.polygons containsObject:overlay])
            {
                pv.fillColor = pgc.color;
                pv.alpha = pgc.alpha;
                break;
            }
        }

        return pv;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

**However**, for this to work right, you'll have to slightly change where you call `addOverlay`.  In the code you've shown, you are calling `addOverlay` before adding it to the polygons array and before adding the group to the mypolygroups array.  This can cause `viewForOverlay` to fire before the arrays contain data.

Instead, move just the `addOverlay` calls to after the `mypolygroups` array is fully populated.  So after adding the last group to `mypolygroups`:

```
...
[self.mypolygroups addObject:theLastPolygroup];

for (PolyGonGroupClass *pgc in mypolygroups) 
{
    for (MKPolygon *p in pgc.polygons) 
    {
        [mapView addOverlay:p];
    }
}
```

Finally, to update a group's color and alpha later after it's already on the map, you can do something like this:

```
//pgc is some instance of PolyGonGroupClass
pgc.alpha = newAlpha;
pgc.color = newColor;

for (MKPolygon *p in pgc.polygons) 
{
    MKPolygonView *pv = (MKPolygonView *)[mapView viewForOverlay:p];
    pv.alpha = pgc.alpha;
    pv.fillColor = pgc.color;
}
```